open activity from background service
I have implemented FOREGROUND service in MAUI. I want to open page (MainPage or another project's contentpage) defined in my MAUI application from FOREGROUND service on specific condition.
I tried below code :
var lockScreen = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
lockScreen.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.BroughtToFront);
this.StartActivity(lockScreen);

But nothing happen. Should I make any changes in AndroidManifest.xml?
If MainActivity does not work , I created PinActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity , how I can implement rendering of project's ContentPage (PinActivity ) from  OnCreate method in PinActivity ?

Where did you put the code? And did you mean you want to open the special page when the user tap the foreground service notification?

In  https://github.com/carlfranklin/MAUIAndroidFS/blob/master/Maui%20XAML%20Version/MAUIAndroidFS/MAUIAndroidFS/Platforms/Android/MyBackgroundService.cs Timer_Elapsed I want to open my page without user tap notification.
below code is working fine in pure android project:
val lockScreen = Intent(context, LockScreen::class.java)
lockScreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)
context.startActivity(lockScreen)

That's because you launch another activty but there is only a mainactivity in the maui android part. In addition, is the mainactivity in the background or foreground when you call the code above?

the mainactivity is in background, another app in foreground and I would like to bring my lock screen activity. When you say I lunch another activity - what do you mean? I will to open any activity from my MAUI project

What does the another app mean? There are many activies in pure android project. But there is only one mainactivity in maui and many contentpages.

means that in foreground is running another app - clock for example.
In my service I want to open activity (MainActivity or anything else (ContentPage) which will be opened as foreground application.
Again same code in pure android is working fine. I need help with MAUI implemntation.

What does But nothing happen mean in your question. I can't understand the result you want after you call the code above. Did you want to show the lockscreen contentpage in the mainactivty, or you want to open another lockscreen activity when the mainactivity is showing.

@VladimirB allow me to point out something important for MAUI. A ContentPage does not directly correspond to an Activity. MAUI is more like using Jetpack Compose. So in a way, your Main activity is "anything else".

I want to open my MAUI application from foreground service. Will it be MainActivity or another activity does not matter. When I call example of my code - my app does not go to foreground.

I have checked the code in your github repo. I can't find above code in your service. And I tried the pendingintent in your service and it can open the mainactivity.

I can upload complete project - just add into Timer_Elapsed method my 3 lines. Then during test, open Clock application. After 10 sec -  expectation is that  my app will go to foreground instead of Clock. In pure android it is working clean.
Pendingintent is not relevant since I want to open mainactivity to foreground without user click on notification.

What's the target android sdk in your pure android? The .net 7 targets android 33. Did you read the official document about Restrictions on starting activities from the background?

the targetSdkVersion was 29, I changed it to 33 and it is still working. I have the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission in the Manifest
and I Prompt the user to grant the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission within my app, when not already granted

Could you please show the steps to how to reproduce this problem? Or could you please provide a smallest sample that can reproduce this?

It seems working in debug but crashing when it running without debug (in log I see open_from_bundles:failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.dll, open_from_bundles:failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.dll and another related to my project). Below repository
https://github.com/vovanb/MAUIAndroidFS

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
